# Get built status of a job in jenkins using selenium

Tags: java, jenkins

I want to check the jenkins job built status() by using selenium webdriver. 
There are many jobs are running in jenkins but one of the jobs is running at every hour so I want to check the how many times that particular job has built successfully/failed in last 24 hours, along with time. Is there any way available so that I can hit the jenkins url to get the built status.

I have gone through to some links and found that some developers are using jenkins cli to get the build status but I did not find anyway to get the status by selenium.Seeking your guidance in this regard. I want to accomplish this task by using java.
Thanks in Advance.

// no code till now

built-no  built-status  built-time

123463    Success   Dec 24, 2018 11:51:12 PM

123462    failed    Dec 24, 2018 10:51:12 PM

.....     .......   .......................

12345     Success   Dec 24, 2018 5:51:12 AM

12344     Failed    Dec 24, 2018 4:51:12 AM

12343     Success   Dec 24, 2018 3:51:12 AM

12342     Success   Dec 24, 2018 2:51:12 AM

12341     Success   Dec 24, 2018 1:51:12 AM

Comment: How is this question related to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB , I just want to write a code which can find the last built, as the job should run without any manual intervention such as login to jenkins and get last successful built time, so I am trying to use selenium, may be I am on the wrong path, can you please guide me. I am also very new to selenium just few days back assigned a task to prepare a report using selenium.

Answer (score 3):

From [Seleniumhq](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) website,

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! Primarily, it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that. Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should!) be automated as well.

So it is not recommended to use Selenium to get build status from Jenkins. Like you wanted, you can accomplish this using Java with Jenkins API.

In general, url of Jenkins job would be like <Jenkins url>/job/<Job_name>. One can see more available options by appending **/api** to above url.

Jenkins exposes many details through remote access API and one can see a job metadata in JSON/XML format by appending json or xml to above url.

**Example:**

1. <Jenkins url>/job/<Job_name>/api/json
2. <Jenkins url>/job/<Job_name>/api/xml

The '**tree**' query parameter allows users to explicitly specify and retrieve only the information they are looking for.

In your case, **<Jenkins url>/job/<Job_name>/api/json?tree=allBuilds[result,number,url,timestamp]** api will give you the details in json format from which you can calculate all the data you wanted like number of builds triggered, passed and/or failed in last 24 hours.

Sample response for above url would be like below.

```
{
  "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject",
  "allBuilds": [
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "number": 7,
      "result": "SUCCESS",
      "timestamp": 1545661232289,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/RegressionTest/7/"
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "number": 6,
      "result": "SUCCESS",
      "timestamp": 1545658820048,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/RegressionTest/6/"
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "number": 5,
      "result": "SUCCESS",
      "timestamp": 1545658814132,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/RegressionTest/5/"
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "number": 4,
      "result": "FAILURE",
      "timestamp": 1545658799754,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/RegressionTest/4/"
    },
    {
      "_class": "hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild",
      "number": 3,
      "result": "FAILURE",
      "timestamp": 1545658784937,
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/RegressionTest/3/"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use Java json libraries to parse and manipulate data in the way you wanted.

Use api **<Jenkins url>/job/<Job_name>/api/xml?tree=allBuilds[result,number,url,timestamp]** to get same data in xml format.

Please note that everything specified here is at job level.

Comment: while navigating to the jenkins url and reading the json data through a java code I am getting the 500 error, is this due to login credentials??